# Unable to Create Active Directory user group in Azure SQL using PowerShell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, devops

I am trying to add active directory user group to azure sql databases through PowerShell, but unable to do so. I am using SQL administrator login to achieve it. When i execute my code it gives me below error.

*Principal 'abc' could not be created. Only connections established with Active Directory accounts can create other Active Directory users.*

When I use my active directory account to create users it then gives me below error.

*Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Cannot open server "domain name" requested by the login.  The login failed..*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL does not support AD integration, Only supports `Azure Active Directory` and `SQL authentication`. If there is need for AD integration then choose one of the following option:

- SQL Server on VM - Unmanaged SQL server with full access to SQL instance.
- Federated authentication with ADFS infrastructure, refer to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview